# How to iterate an array with vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector, multidimensional-array

I have a set of vectors of length *n*, say, for example that *n=3*:

```
vec1<-c(1,2,3)
vec2<-c(2,2,2)
```

And a multidimensional array of size *n^n*:

```
threeDarray<-array(0,dim=c(3,3,3))
```

I want to create a loop that goes through my set of vectors and adds 1 to the corresponding index in the array. After analysing the two vectors above the array should be like:

```
threeDarray[1,2,3]=1
threeDarray[2,2,2]=1
```

I'm trying to use the multidimensional array to store the number of occurrences of each vector (my vectors are patterns in a time series).

Comment: Note: "3Darray" is not a valid name.

Comment: Why not use a matrix or data frame?

Comment: My bad @Pascal. It's corrected.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen isn't there a way to do it? Maybe I'm overcomplicating this stuff. My objective in the end is to calculate the [Permutation Entropy](http://www.math.uni-bremen.de/zetem/DFG-Schwerpunkt/preprints/orig/bandt_pompe_permutation.pdf). Although I would also like to learn if this is possible...

Comment: You could put your vectors in a list (could use `temp <- mget(ls(pattern = "vec\\d+"))` if there are many) and simply do something like `temp <- list(vec1, vec2) ; for(i in 1:length(temp)) threeDarray[temp[[i]][1],temp[[i]][2],temp[[i]][3]] <- 1`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thank you. Your second chunk of code does exactly what I want. The only "imperfection" is that I need to change my code depending on the   dimension of the matrix (for n=4, I have to add `temp[[i]][4]`). Is there a way to automatize this? If you post it as an answer I'll select it as the correct one.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a four dimensional array? How do even use it why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community is right (and the noob is wrong). Multidimensional arrays are not the way to go about this.

An example of code working with lists:

```
freqPatterns<-function(timeSeries,dimension){
 temp<-character()
 for (i in 1:(length(timeSeries)-dimension+1)){
  pattern<-paste(as.character(rank(timeSeries[i:(i+dimension-1)])-1),collapse=", ")
  #print(pattern)
  temp[[length(temp)+1]] <- pattern
 }
 freqTable=sort(table(temp),decreasing=T)
 return(freqTable)
}
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Like you found out yourself, I wouldn't use a multidimensioanl array neither.
Here is a solution using a dataframe:

```
n=4  # dimension
ll = lapply(vector("list", n), function(x) x=1:n) # build list of vectors (n * 1:n)
df_occurs = expand.grid(ll, KEEP.OUT.ATTRS=F)  # get all combinations
df_occurs$occurences = 0

# for-loop for storing the occurences
for(v in list(vec1, vec2)) {
    v_match = apply(df_occurs[,1:n], 1, function(x) all(x==v))
    df_occurs$occurences[v_match] = 1
}
```

Maybe performance is an issue with large n. If it's possible to build a character-key out of your vector, eg.

```
paste(vec1, collapse="")
```

the lookup in the dataframe would be easier:

```
df_occurs = data.frame(
    key = apply(expand.grid(ll, KEEP.OUT.ATTRS=F), 1, paste, collapse=""),
    occurences = 0
)

for(key in list(vec1, vec2)) {
    df_occurs$occurences[df_occurs$key==paste(key, collapse="")] = 1
}
```